# npm installation error in laravel project

Tags: laravel, npm-install

Hello i am using `npm` in my `laravel` project. i installed `npm` and when i command `npm -v`, i receive `5.0.0` . but when i try to `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` i get following error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwn1k.png)

Please help me to resolve this problem. i searched too many in sites but didnt find a way to solve this...

Comment: What version of `laravel-mix` are you using? Upgrading your `npm` and `node` may resolve this problem.

Comment: lararvel-mix : 5.0.1 @JulioMotol

Comment: @JulioMotol how can i update ?

Comment: Try updating `npm` first by running `npm install -g npm@latest`.

Comment: @JulioMotol It updated successfully but same error when i try to npm run watch:((

Comment: @JulioMotol Could it be because of the sanctions?

Comment: What sanctions? What version of node are you using?

Comment: @JulioMotol Sanctions against Iran . V5.0.0

Comment: I highly doubt that, its a compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating node:

#### Windows OS

Get the stable installer in [Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/)

#### Linux OS

```
npm install n -g
n stable
```